# What is the best practice for the location of Java application configuration files?

Tags: java, configuration, properties, project-structure

Is there a best practice for where configuration files should be stored in a Java project. The file type is a Java properties file in this case, but I do use other file types in other projects.

Would the recommendation vary from stand alone application(.jar) to web app(.war)?

Comment: Do you want to be able to change the configuration after you do a build or do you want the configuration to be part of the .jar/.war file you build?

Comment: @ScArcher2, for our production release around here we have make release requests, so changing the config file is just as much of a hassle as doing the entire package file. So I've come to prefer keeping the configuration in the package

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll find that many open-source projects follow the [directory structure used by Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). In this setup your application source code is kept in src/main/java, application resources, including properties files, in src/main/resources, and other config files in src/main/config. Files related to unit tests use a similar directory structure; src/test/java and src/test/resources.

Personally I tend to use this layout because of its widespread use. I also keep an "etc" directory beneath the project root to house files that aren't directly related to the application. For example, I keep configuration files for PMD and Checkstyle in etc.

Answer (score 4):

In general a common practice is to have a `resources` directory for configuration files which is copied into the build artifact by the build process.  Maven uses this in its [default project structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).  Within the `resources` directory, you might also have a `META-INF` directory and/or a `WEB-INF` directory in an application packaged as a war.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

- *META-INF/* for **jar** files
- *WEB-INF/* for **war** files